# How to notify a binding handler the content is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm creating a binding handler to work with carousel based on a js object given by my API. For test purposes, I'm loading the content statically.

I have the following object:

```
self.images = [
    { 
      imageUrl: 'http://www.triptips.com.br/site/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/castillo-praga.jpg', 
      description: 'Photo from Praga.' 
    },
    { 
      imageUrl: 'http://www.4yourevista.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/berlim-01-4you.jpg', 
      description: 'Photo from Berlim.' },
    { 
      imageUrl: 'http://cdni.wired.co.uk/1920x1280/k_n/London_5.jpg', 
      description: 'Photo from London.' },
    { 
      imageUrl: 'http://www.dudalinafeminina.com.br/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/paris2.jpg', 
      description: 'Photo from Paris.' },
    { 
      imageUrl: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e1/1_hongkong_panorama_victoria_peak_2011.JPG', 
      description: 'Photo from Hong Kong.' }
];
```

Well, once the imageUrl will be loaded from another place, it'll take some time to get fully loaded.

I'm creating this handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.carousel = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(element).slick({ ... }); // this is the slider component
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    }
}
```

Working with static content (such as some text), it works fine. However, when I try to use this binding with a `foreach` iteration, it doesn't works.

```
<div class="centered" data-bind="carousel: {}, foreach: images">
    <div>
        <img alt="" data-bind="attr: { src: imageUrl, title: description }" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you for all the help!

Comment: Bindings are run in the order they are found. Maybe inverting them will solve this (`<div class="centered" data-bind="foreach: images, carousel: {}">`)

Comment: There was a very similar question recently about lazy loading images and knockout bindings that I think you may find helpful - I will look around but you should also as it was really neat the way they did it.

Comment: @GôTô, works like a charm. Add this as an answer so I can check it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bindings are interpreted in the order they are found.

Here you probably want the `foreach` binding to execute before your `carousel` binding, so try inverting them:

```
<div class="centered" data-bind="foreach: images, carousel: {}">
```